# How to set the property acks = all in properties file of a spring boot application

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, kafka-producer-api, properties-file, message-channel

I have tried the following
spring.kafka.producer.acks= - 1
And
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.requiredAcks= - 1

Both are not working and my MessageChannel.send() is still returning true with all the brokers down

Answer (score 0):

To set acks=all use:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.producer-properties.acks=all
```

If you want to set for a particular channel, override as follows:

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.mytopicchannel.producer.configuration.acks=all
```

Ref: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_configuration_options